Processing CSV type file and creating new output using Python (or AWK)
I have a file "linked_policies.txt" that looks like the following (small sample of data):
0000001G|11111111
0000002G|10000018
0000002G|10000320
0000002G|10000337
0000002G|10000343
101359B|10000018
101359B|16023380
504529A|10000018
504529A|15856008
504529A|16007139
504529A|16007151
504529A|16526483
620667G|16526483
0000003G|22222222
0000003G|33333333

The first column represents 'policy' and second column represents 'customer'.
Policy 0000001G is not linked to any other policies as it contains only one customer number not linked to any other policies.
Similarly, Policy 0000003G is not linked to any other policies as it contains two customer numbers not linked to any other policies.
All of the other policies (0000002G, 101359B, 504529A and 620667G) are considered to be linked to each other because for instance policy 0000002G is directly linked to policies 101359B and 504529A (as they all share the same customer 10000018) but policy 0000002G is also indirectly linked to policy 620667G because even though they do not share a customer number directly between them, policy 620667G shares customer 16526483 with policy 504529A and this policy itself has a shared customer with 0000002G so therefore all are considered to be linked policies.
I want to process the input file and end up with a new "output_file.txt" whereby for each policy, the policy is listed in the first column and in the second column (space delimited between first and second column) the list of associated policy/ies are listed (including the policy in question itself).  For example, from the sample input file following processing, file "output_file.txt" would look as follows:
0000001G 0000001G
0000002G 0000002G|101359B|504529A|620667G
101359B 101359B|0000002G|504529A|620667G
504529A 504529A|0000002G|101359B|620667G
0000003G 0000003G

First column shows each unique policy number (from the input file) and the second column shows all of the policy/ies that this policy is directly or indirectly linked to.
Looking for a way for this to be done using either AWK or Python  (noting that the Python version available to me is earlier than version 3.6)
My (Python) script "linked_policies.py" attempt is as follows:
# Read the input data
with open('linked_policies.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Create a dictionary to store the customers and their associated policies
customer_policies = {}

# Iterate through the lines
for line in lines:
    # Split the line into policy and customer
    policy, customer = line.strip().split('|')

    # Add the customer to the customer_policies dictionary
    if customer not in customer_policies:
        customer_policies[customer] = set()
    customer_policies[customer].add(policy)

# Create a dictionary to store the linked policies
linked_policies = {}

# Link policies based on shared customers
for customer, policies in customer_policies.items():
    for policy in policies:
        if policy not in linked_policies:
            linked_policies[policy] = set(policies)
        else:
            linked_policies[policy].update(policies)

# Write the output to a file
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for policy, linked_policies_set in linked_policies.items():
        linked_policies_str = '|'.join(sorted(linked_policies_set))
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(policy, linked_policies_str))

When I run this:
python ./linked_policies.py

....the resulting output file "output_file.txt" looks like this:
620667G 504529A|620667G
504529A 0000002G|101359B|504529A|620667G
0000003G 0000003G
0000002G 0000002G|101359B|504529A
101359B 0000002G|101359B|504529A
0000001G 0000001G

The second, third and sixth lines are all correct.
The other lines are incorrect (first, fourth and fifth lines) as they are not correctly showing all of the linked policies.

OP has posted that the original awk answer (see 2nd half of this answer) ran for a few minutes and then ran out of memory (on a host with 23 GB of RAM).
Here'a rewrite using 1-dimensional arrays:
awk '
function get_customer (p,  c, i, n) {
    n = split(pol_cus[p],c,",")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        get_policy(c[i])
}
function get_policy (c,  p, i, n) {
    n = split(cus_pol[c],p,",")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        if (! (p[i] in links)) {
           links[p[i]]
           get_customer(p[i])
        }
}

BEGIN { FS = "|" }
      { sep = ($1 in pol_cus) ? "," : ""
        pol_cus[$1] = pol_cus[$1] sep $2

        sep = ($2 in cus_pol) ? "," : ""
        cus_pol[$2] = cus_pol[$2] sep $1
      }

END   { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (policy in pol_cus) {
            delete links
            links[policy]
            get_customer(policy)
            delete links[policy]
            printf "%s %s", policy, policy
            for (link in links)
                printf "|%s", link
            print ""
        }
      }
' policy.dat

To simulate OP's environment I used the following script:
awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1;i<=2900000;i++)
             printf "p%07d|c%07d\np%07d|C%07d\n", i,i,i,i+1
           }
' > policy.big.dat

The resulting file:
104 MBytes in size
5.8 million lines
2.9 million unique policy #s
5.8 million unique customer #s

Test environment:
i7-1260P
64 GB RAM
gawk v 5.1.0

Results of running both awk scripts against the 104 MByte, 5.8 million line policy.big.dat file:
                              RAM       time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
awk (2-dimensional arrays)    4.4 GB    12 secs
awk (1-dimensional arrays)    2.6 GB    14 secs

A diff of the two resulting data sets report no differences.
Running the same tests in a virtual machine (Windows 10, 16 GB RAM, gawk v 5.3.0) and making sure Windows Antimalware service is disabled:
                              RAM       time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
awk (2-dimensional arrays)    7.5 GB    17 secs
awk (1-dimensional arrays)    2.9 GB    24 secs

Not sure at this point how the original awk answer (below) could take minutes to run and generate an OOM error on OP's host with 23 GB of RAM ...

Original answer
General approach:

save policy/customer and customer/policy pairs in 2-dimensional array
for each policy in the policy/customer array recursively search for linked policies

One awk approach:
awk '
function get_customer (p,  c) {
    for (c in pol_cus[p])                          # for each customer associated with this policy ...
        get_policy(c)                              # find the associated policies
}
function get_policy (c,  p) {
    for (p in cus_pol[c])                          # for each policy associated with this customer ...
        if (! (p in links)) {                      # if we have not seen this policy yet then ...
           links[p]                                # add to our list of links and then ...
           get_customer(p)                         # find the associated customer(s)
        }
}

BEGIN { FS = "|" }
      { pol_cus[$1][$2]                            # policy/customer array
        cus_pol[$2][$1]                            # customer/policy array
      }
END   { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"     # process array indices in sorted order
        for (policy in pol_cus) {                  # loop through our list of policies
            delete links                           # clear list of links
            links[policy]                          # self link this policy; insures recursive search halts if we see this policy again
            get_customer(policy)                   # start the recursive search
            delete links[policy]                   # delete the self link
            printf "%s %s", policy, policy
            for (link in links)                    # loop through links and append to current line of output
                printf "|%s", link
            print ""                               # terminate current line of output
        }
      }
' policy.dat

NOTES:

requires GNU awk for a) multi-dimensional arrays (aka array of arrays) and b) sorting the policies (via PROCINFO["sorted_in"])
if sorting is not required you can remove the line PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
see predefined array scanning orders for details on PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"

This generates:
0000001G 0000001G
0000002G 0000002G|101359B|504529A|620667G
0000003G 0000003G
101359B 101359B|0000002G|504529A|620667G
504529A 504529A|0000002G|101359B|620667G
620667G 620667G|0000002G|101359B|504529A


I believe this is due to the fact that you are looping through the customer_policies once, so if new links are found further in the loop, they are not retroactively applied to earlier policies. For example, the 0000002G item will never know about the 504529A item based on your example order.
The kind of data structure you want here is probably a graph, where each policy is a "node" and when you connect them, all the other associated nodes come along.
However, here is a quick (inefficient) solution to get you started if your list size is relatively small. I believe it calculates in n^2 time, if not higher.
# This follows the "# Link policies based on shared customers"
# It loops through the linked_policies from prev step and applies them to every item in the list where found.

# Combine all sets 
linked_and_combined_policies = {}
for policy, _linked_policies in linked_policies.items():
    linked_and_combined_policies[policy] = set()
    for linked in _linked_policies:
        linked_and_combined_policies[policy].update(linked_policies[linked])

for policy, combined_policies_set in linked_and_combined_policies.items():
    linked_policies_str = '|'.join(sorted(combined_policies_set))


When I run the supplied AWK script on the small sample data input file it works as expected.
However if I run the same script on a much bigger input file (82 MB, 4 million rows) it runs for a few minutes but then I get the following reported in the nohup.out file:
nohup time gawk -f linked_policies.gawk linked_policies.txt &

Command terminated by signal 9

30.90user 104.05system 4:23.86elapsed 51%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 23961300maxresident)k 1573832inputs+0outputs
(162969major+22520293minor)pagefaults 0swaps

....so looks like it may have hit a resourcing issue??
Is there anyway around this?

how big (MBytes) is the file?  how much memory do you have on this machine? remove or comment out the PROCINFO["sorted_in"] line (but make sure you don't remove/comment-out the first 5 characters of the line - END {); how many unique policy and customer numbers are in the big file (tr '|' '\n' < policy.dat | sort -u | wc -l)

we're saving the entire file in memory; multi-dimensional arrays (unfortunately) can increase memory usage by 2x-5x; the PROCINFO["sorted_in"] construct is going to require some additional memory, too; while the awk code can be rewritten to eliminate the multi-dimensional arrays it would help to have more details (eg,, # of uniq strings); would be curious to know ... what happens if you run iain's python code ... does it complete? does it generate the correct results?

The file is 84 Mbytes with 4.69 million rows in it. There are 2.9 million unique policies and 4.6 million unique customer numbers.    Memory on machine is 23GB available RAM with 67GB Swap.  I tried iain's Python code on the small sample data and it completed but did not generate the correct results.   I managed to achieve what I needed using a Ruby script and surprisingly it only took 1 min and 6 seconds to complete processing the big file.  Thanks again for the help!

fwiw I've updated the answer to include an awk script that uses 1-dimensional arrays which equates to less memory usage in return for a slightly longer run time; I also include my test file and the memory usage and timing results for both awk answers; not sure at this point how your system can take minutes to run while also using up all 23 GB of ram ... ???
